# How to make fixed input stay at bottom?

Tags: html, css, css-position

First, I'd like to say, I was unable to think of a better question name other than the name above. My problem certainly does not only regard a fixed input. I'll explain my problem in great detail here.

### Basic Information

So, I am making a real-time chat website. The website will be in a `body { display: grid }` fashion. There are three columns: the first for the list of chats you have, the second for the messages in the current chat you've selected, and the third one to show all the online users in the chat you've selected to view. The first and third columns are to be 20% of the width of the page, each. And the middle one (the one which contains the messages) is to be set to an `auto` width (meaning that it takes up the rest of the space available, in this case, it's 60% of the page). I have no questions about the first and third columns. My issue only revolves around the second/middle one.

This middle column will have a chat area (a place where all the messages pop up) and at the bottom, a `form`, with a text `input` and a `submit` button. This middle column, at the moment, is not `display flex` or `display: grid`.

### What I Want

Certainly, after a lot of messages appear, the `div` that contains all these messages will `overflow`. So, I've added `overflow: auto` to this `div` to make the scrollbar appear, if needed. Since the `div` and the `form` below it are separated by a `margin`, the scrollbar appears only on the `div` and the `form` below it is unaffected.

I would like to have the `form` at the bottom of this `div` but have all message `overflow` to be styled so that these messages appear to go under the form. [image: Much like what Discord and Guilded have (image attachment).] As seen in this image, the messages go UNDER the `input`, if the user scrolls further up. If further explanation is necessary for clarification, I'll be happy to help.

### What I've Tried/Problems

I have tried adding `position: fixed` and `bottom: 0` to the `form` so that it stays at the bottom. That turns into [image: this], which is the desired result. So far so good.

If I send a message, I want the format to stay, so I made sure, which [image: worked] (ignore the space to the left of the username `JohnDoe` and the content; that's where the user profile will go). Again, everything still works.

Now, for the final test, I wanted to make sure that the message overflow works as intended (with a scrollbar), and if I scroll up, the messages appear to "go under" the `form`, like the image I showed above. After a few messages, it turns into [image: this], which is intended. And if I were to scroll up, [image: the messages do appear to go under the form].

But, that only works for a few messages. After more messages pile in, this doesn't stay. [image: This] is what it looks like after a few more messages. If it isn't visible at the first glance, here's an explanation: the `input` started getting pushed farther and farther down the page until I can only see half of it (hence, only half the input was visible in the image). If I were to keep sending messages, the input would fully go off the page.

### My Code

If you would like to check for errors clearly, here's the code that I have so far:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu&display=swap");

* {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Ubuntu, "Segoe UI", Roboto,
    Oxygen, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  background-color: #36393e;
  color: #fff;
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% auto 20%;
}

.chat-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}

.chat-box {
  height: 90%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-right: 8px;
}

.chat-message {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 65px auto;
}

.chat-message:hover {
  background-color: #27292e;
}

.message-time {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  opacity: 50%;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.chat-message:hover > .message-time {
  visibility: visible;
}

.message-user {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.username {
  margin-right: 15px;
  color: #50c878;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.user-time {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.form-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  width: 60%;
}

.message-form {
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #40444d;
  border-radius: 5px;
  flex-grow: 2;
  height: 40px;
}

.message {
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  flex-grow: 2;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.send {
  text-align: center;
  height: 40px;
  min-width: 50px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 50%;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.send:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 75%;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 5px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: transparent;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #121214;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!--
I have premade messages for you to see what the format would look like. If you would like to add more messages, please use the format below (add this code into #chat-box) :

<div class="chat-message">
  <div></div>
  <div class="message-user">
    <div class="user-time">
    <span id="username" data-username="JohnDoe" class="username">Username</span>
    <span class="message-time">12:00 PM</span>
  </div>
  <span class="message-content">Message content</span>
</div>
</div>

It turns out that the username will appear in every message, even when not needed. This is prevented by JavaScript, which isn't added here.
-->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

<head>
  <title>Chat</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="chat-list-wrapper"></div>

  <div class="chat-wrapper">
    <div id="chat-box" class="chat-box">
      <div class="chat-message">
        <div></div>
        <div class="message-user">
          <div class="user-time">
            <span id="username" data-username="JohnDoe" class="username">JohnDoe</span>
            <span class="message-time">1:35 PM</span>
          </div>
          <span class="message-content">Testing.</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-wrapper">
      <form id="message-form" class="message-form">
        <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="Send a message..." class="message" id="message" />
        <button type="submit" name="send" class="send" id="send">
          <!-- <i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i>  not working on SO-->
          Send
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="status-wrapper"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

If you would like any clarification of anything here, please comment below. I'll be glad to help.

I've been stuck on this issue for a couple of days now. Thank you in advance. All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after many hours of work, I've finally got it fixed. I didn't have to use `position: fixed` to keep the `input` at the bottom. All I needed to do was just make sure that the `chat-box` had a fixed `height` (which allowed it to start scrolling). Then make sure that `chat-wrapper` had a fixed `height` as well (otherwise, the whole page starts scrolling since the `chat-wrapper` didn't have a fixed height, so `chat-box` would just fill up 90% of it, and since `chat-wrapper` could grow infinitely, so could `chat-box`).

The `input` automatically stood in place, and now I have the `grid` layout as well as the `input` at the bottom, as intended.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you removed the 100% height for your form-wrapper (it appears to not be important) and added a bottom: 0 or some spacing like 10 px it would work.

```css
.form-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 60%;
}
```